# How do i connect to Tuxedo using wsnaddr?

Tags: middleware, tuxedo

How do i connect to Tuxedo using `wsnaddr`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a workstation client built using the buildclient tool (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13161_01/tuxedo/docs10gr3/rfcm/rfcmd.html#wp998347) and have WSNADDR set as an environment variable.

The syntax is a bit peculiar - it's **//:** - so connecting to a server named 'danger-room' on port 5550 would use a WSNADDR of //danger-room:5550

The Tuxedo domain being connected to must have a WSL server configured using that listen address (set in its CLOPT parameters), and the machine that the WSL is listening on must have a MAXWSCLIENTS setting greater than zero.

If all of those parts are configured consistently, a WSL client connection can be made successfully.

If you're looking at testing network connectivity, I'd suggest starting with one of the sample applications like simpapp (which is bundled with a Tuxedo install) and modifying it to use a WSL.

Answer (score 0):

With Tuxedo version 10 onwards you also have a .net client available for tuxedo which you can use in order to develop and test /WS based tuxedo applications.

Also in WDNADDR you can specify comma separated values if you want to connect to alternative WSH in case first one fails.